# css spilling from on svg style to the other

Tags: css, svg, styles

I have this [webfirme.ro/rig](http://www.webfirme.ro/rig/)

How can I stop the color from spilling from `img_1` (the SVG from the left) to the one in the right?

Both have something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
   .fil1 {fill:#028553}
   .fil4 {fill:#FA0000}
   ]]>
```

and the second if has the fill green makes the first also green.

Example: select `MLT_116c` (from the FIRST) and then `BMC_375` (from the second).

How can I encapsulate the style without modifying the xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the SVG XML data via an `<object>` or `<iframe>` tag. Then they will be in separate documents and their CSS styles will not interfere with each other.

Comment: Yes, although if you're doing that from the html page you need to get a reference to the object/iframe and then get the contentDocument. See https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-object.html

Comment: just wrapping the svg data with <object> or <iframe> tags doesn't work for me. The styles are still used globally. https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/RLPgpW

Comment: @JulesColle you use external files with object/iframe or data URLs if you want one file. You don't "wrap" anything.